# Octoperf - Specifying custom / third-party dependencies - where does Octoperf pull dependencies from?

Tags: performance-testing

I am exploring the option of using Octoperf as a hosted solution.

One thing that I need is the ability to call some custom libraries (either Java or Javascript / Node.js).

In the SCRIPT PRE and SCRIPT POST examples in the Octoperf documentation I see calls being made to `import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch`. However, it is not clear to me how Octoperf knows where to pull this dependency from.

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify this and how?

Answer (score 0):

this dependency in your example is already included in every JVM. If you need to add other dependencies in OctoPerf, just place them in the files menu of your project and they will be copied to lib/ext when the test is started:
https://doc.octoperf.com/design/edit-virtual-user/configuration/files/